# What does ASIFileManagementError mean?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am using ASI to download files and I keep seeing `ASIFileManagementError`.  I am guessing that means that there is something wrong with how I'm building the download paths for my requests but it's not consistent.  Sometimes the download works just fine and other times it fails.  Even when using the same code on the same device to download the same file!  Here is my code.

```
-(ASIHTTPRequest*)buildDownloadLinkForUpdate:(ContentItem*)update
{
    NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@", update.downloadUrl.absoluteString, @"auth_token", database.userAuthToken];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

    ContentItem* item = [database getItemWithId:update.uniqueId];
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:item.contentPath];
    [request setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:[[AppSettings instance].temporaryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:item.fileName]];
    [request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:TRUE];
    [request setShowAccurateProgress: TRUE];
    [request setDelegate:[_currentItem progressDelegate]];

    return request;
}

-(void)initalizeNetworkQueue
{
    if(!networkQueue) networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];

    [networkQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [networkQueue reset];

    if([_currentItem progressDelegate])
    {
        [networkQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:[_currentItem progressDelegate]];
    }

    [networkQueue setDelegate:self];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(networkQueueComplete:)];
    [networkQueue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(networkQueueFailed:)];
    [networkQueue setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
    networkQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
}
```

And then here is the code that actually invokes this:

```
[self initalizeNetworkQueue];
[networkQueue addOperation:[self buildDownloadLinkForUpdate:_currentUpdate]];
[networkQueue go];
currentState = ContentUpdaterStateDownloading;
```

Is there something obviously wrong here?

-= UPDATE=- 
It's saying that it's failing because it's unable to move the file from the temporary location to the final location.

`Download Failed: Failed to move file from '/var/mobile/Applications/33E1DF3C-17F5-432F-8204-A9B53AB5AAE3/Documents/.temp/FileShare+Gate+4.pptx' to '/var/mobile/Applications/33E1DF3C-17F5-432F-8204-A9B53AB5AAE3/Documents/.content/FileShare+Gate+4.pptx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error before, it was in the connection, it is of type `ASINetworkErrorType`, it means that the host cannot be reached.

Anyway `ASIHttprequest` is dead now, you will not find answers for many questions you have, take my advice and go with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it is great and do the job.